# How to save names from json to list in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to save all names from a json url to a list but it doesn’t work.

I am using this code:

```
let jsonUrl = ("https://de1.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/byname/jazz")
Alamofire.request( jsonUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        
        for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in swiftyJsonVar {
            
            for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in subJson {
                
                let nameList = subJson["name"].stringValue
                print(nameList)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What about using Codable instead of I guess SwiftyJSON? SwiftyJSON is kind of deprecated since Codable.

Comment: If you're using AlamoFire and/or SwiftyJSON, add that info to your question. As Larme says, you should probably switch to using Codable. It's gotten a lot easier, and there's not much point in using SwiftyJSON any more.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I should try Codable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Codable structs makes this kind of tasks a lot easier.

Consider this:

```
//Create a struct that contains the values you are interested in
struct NameResponse: Codable{
    var name: String
}

let jsonUrl = ("https://de1.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/byname/jazz")

    Alamofire.request( jsonUrl).responseData { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            //Now decode the response data to an array of your structs
            let names = try! JSONDecoder().decode([NameResponse].self, from: responseData.result.value!)
            //Now you can map them to an array or process them anyway you want
            let nameArray = names.map{$0.name}
            print(nameArray)
        }
}
```

Edit:

If you need the data from an Alamofire response you would need to call the `.responseData` handler instead of the `.responseJSON` one.

Comment: Thanks, but I get error: Cannot find ’data’ in scope.

Comment: Side note: It'd be good to use `if let` to unwrap, rather than using old Swift "if != nil + force unwrap".

Comment: @Larme I agree. But I tried to change the code as little as possible.

Comment: But that could be a "side note" to your answer, or someone that read my comment after your answer while your main answer focus on the issue. That's fine by me. I'd even add to go further, that checking `responseData` as a `Result` would be good too.

Comment: Okay, now I get error: Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data'. Insert ' as! Data'. And when I insert that the app crashes.

Comment: @MatKoffman please see my updated answer.